# How to enable an editing adorner when the adorned element is disabled in TreeView?

Tags: wpf, treeview, adorner

WPF

I have a TreeView (see below) for which I have created an Editing Adorner.
All works correctly. However, I would like to disable the TreeView while editing is in progress. When the TreeView is disabled -- as well as the element being adorned for editing -- the adorner is also being disabled.

How can the TreeView be disabled (IsEnabled = false) but still allow the Adorner to be enabled for editing?

TIA

```
namespace Doctor_Desk.Views.Adorners
{
    public class EditSelectedItemAdorner : Adorner
    {
        private VisualCollection _Visuals;
        private UIElement _UIElement;
        private bool _IsCancel = false;
        private TextBox _Textbox;

        protected override int VisualChildrenCount
        {
            get
            {
                return _Visuals.Count;
            }
        }

        // Be sure to call the base class constructor.
        public EditSelectedItemAdorner(UIElement adornedElement, IConsultantTreeItem selectedItem)
          : base(adornedElement)
        {
            _UIElement = adornedElement;
            adornedElement.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

            _Textbox = new TextBox
            {
                Background = Brushes.Pink,
                Text = selectedItem.GetText()
            };

            // The VisualCollection will hold the content of this Adorner.
            _Visuals = new VisualCollection(this)
            {
                // The _Textbox is a logical child of the VisualCollection of the Adorner. The ArrangeOverride and MeasureOverride 
                // will set up the Grid control for correct rendering.
                _Textbox   // Adding a single control for display.
            };

        }



        /// The adorner placement is always relative to the top left corner of the adorned element. The children of the adorner are located by
        /// implementing ArrangeOverride. The only other way to position the Adorner content is to use the AdornerPanel Class 
        /// with it's AdornerPlacementCollection Methods.
        /// 
        /// Overriding the default ArrangeOverride and MeasureOverride allows a control to be placed and diplayed in the VisualCollection.
        protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
        {
            //TextBox child = _Visuals[0] as TextBox;
            //FrameworkElement element = _UIElement as FrameworkElement;
            //if (element != null)
            //{
            //    Size textBoxSize = new Size(Math.Max(150, element.DesiredSize.Width), Math.Max(30, element.DesiredSize.Height));
            //    Point location = new Point((this.Width - textBoxSize.Width) / 2,
            //        (textBoxSize.Height - this.Height) / 2);
            //    child.Arrange(new Rect(location, textBoxSize));
            //}

            TextBox child = _Visuals[0] as TextBox;
            Rect adornedElementRect = new Rect(this.AdornedElement.DesiredSize);
            child.Arrange(adornedElementRect);

            return base.ArrangeOverride(finalSize);
        }

        // Overriding the default ArrangeOverride and MeasureOverride allows a control to be diplayed in the VisualCollection.
        protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
        {
            _Textbox.Measure(constraint);
            return _Textbox.DesiredSize;
        }

        protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
        {
            return _Visuals[index];
        }

        // A common way to implement an adorner's rendering behavior is to override the OnRender
        // method, which is called by the layout system as part of a rendering pass.
        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
        {
            Rect adornedElementRect = new Rect(this.AdornedElement.DesiredSize);

            // Some arbitrary drawing implements.
            SolidColorBrush renderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green)
            {
                Opacity = 0.2
            };
            Pen renderPen = new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Navy), 1.5);
            double renderRadius = 5.0;

            // Draw a circle at each corner.
            drawingContext.DrawEllipse(renderBrush, renderPen, adornedElementRect.TopLeft, renderRadius, renderRadius);
            drawingContext.DrawEllipse(renderBrush, renderPen, adornedElementRect.TopRight, renderRadius, renderRadius);
            drawingContext.DrawEllipse(renderBrush, renderPen, adornedElementRect.BottomLeft, renderRadius, renderRadius);
            drawingContext.DrawEllipse(renderBrush, renderPen, adornedElementRect.BottomRight, renderRadius, renderRadius);
        }



        public string Text
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Text.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(EditSelectedItemAdorner), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));


    }
}



 <TreeView  Grid.Row="2"  Grid.Column="2"  Grid.RowSpan="4"  Width="400"
                   ItemsSource="{Binding SpecialityTree}" 
                   >
            <TreeView.Resources>


                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type tree:SpecialityTreeItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Offices}" >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type tree:OfficeTreeItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Doctors}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type tree:DoctorTreeItem}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="  " />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>
            <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
                </Style>
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <b:ConsultantTreeViewBehavior 
                    EditSelectedItem="{Binding IsEditing}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTreeItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    Text="{Binding EditingResult, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                     />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>





namespace Doctor_Desk.Views.Behaviors
{
    public class ConsultantTreeViewBehavior : Behavior<TreeView>
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();

            AssociatedObject.SelectedItemChanged += OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged;
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            base.OnDetaching();

            if (AssociatedObject != null)
            {
                AssociatedObject.SelectedItemChanged -= OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged;
            }
        }

        private void OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
        {
            SelectedItem = e.NewValue;
        }

        #region SelectedItem Property

        public object SelectedItem
        {
            get { return GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(object), typeof(ConsultantTreeViewBehavior), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnSelectedItemChanged));

        private static void OnSelectedItemChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.NewValue is TreeViewItem item)
            {
                item.SetValue(TreeViewItem.IsSelectedProperty, true);
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region [EditSelectedItem]

        public bool EditSelectedItem
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(EditSelectedItemProperty); }
            set { SetValue(EditSelectedItemProperty, value); }
        }

        private EditSelectedItemAdorner _Adorner;

        public AdornerLayer myAdornerLayer { get; set; }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for EditSelectedItem.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty EditSelectedItemProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("EditSelectedItem", typeof(bool), typeof(ConsultantTreeViewBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnEditSelectedItem));

        private static void OnEditSelectedItem(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            {
                var d = sender as ConsultantTreeViewBehavior;
                var h = d.AssociatedObject as TreeView;

                TreeViewItem tvi = h
                       .ItemContainerGenerator
                       .ContainerFromItemRecursive(h.SelectedItem);

                if (tvi is UIElement myItem)
                {
                    d._Adorner = new EditSelectedItemAdorner(myItem, (IConsultantTreeItem)h.SelectedItem);

                    // Must have BindingMode.TwoWay for the Adorner to update this ConsultantTreeViewBehavior.
                    var bindingText = new Binding
                    {
                        Source = d,
                        Path = new PropertyPath(TextProperty),
                        Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
                    };
                    // The TextProperty binds the Text from the EditSelectedItemAdorner to the ConsultantManagerViewModel.
                    BindingOperations.SetBinding(d._Adorner, EditSelectedItemAdorner.TextProperty, bindingText);

                    d.myAdornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(myItem);
                    d.myAdornerLayer.Add(d._Adorner);
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region[Text - xaml binding]
        public string Text
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Text.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(ConsultantTreeViewBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty,
                (s, e) =>
                {

                }));
        #endregion

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in leu of any other answer, it would appear that disabling selection in the TreeView disables all the elements of the TreeView -- including the selected branch. When the selected branch is disabled, so is its editing adorner. Therefore, my workaround is simply to cover that part of the TreeView which is being displayed.

In particular, in the OnRender override, add:

```
 // Find offset of selected item from top of the tree.
        GeneralTransform gt = AdornedElement.TransformToVisual(_TreeView);
        Point offset_to_tree_top = gt.Inverse.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
        drawingContext.DrawRectangle(Brushes.DimGray, null, new Rect( 
        offset_to_tree_top, _TreeView.DesiredSize));
```

This puts a DimGray color over the whole tree except for the editing adorner. Thus, user selection of any other tree item can not occur.